# _.split(" ") more fields in scala RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to extract data from an `RDD[string]` into another `RDD[string]`

the RDD contains data similar to this :

```
17.808  15.749  6.649   -0.548  15.9994
```

I need to multiply 4th and 5th fields of each row and store them into a different `RDD[string]`.

I can use the following code to pull out one field

```
ansRDD = rawRDD(._split(" ")(4)).(_.toFloat)
```

`rawRDD` contains the string.

But I need to pull out both the fields into a single RDD as

```
-0.548  15.9994
```

so that I can simply do

```
answer = ansRDD.foreach(case(a,b) => a*b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define ansRDD as:

```
ansRDD = rawRD.map(item => {val comps=item.split(" "); (comps(3),comps(4)})
```

Comment: when I try to do 

ansRDD.reduce(_ * _). It gives me an error.
I need to obtain
comps(3)*comps(4) for each row.
Can you help me how to do it?

Comment: Well before multiplying you have to convert to float so you can change to (comps(3).toFloat, comps(4).toFloat)

Comment: it gives me output as

(-0.548,15.994)

But I need 

-0.548 15.994 to be able to do multiplication.

Comment: also if I do ansRDD.reduce(_*_), will I get

-0.548*15.994 or values multiplied with their subsequent rows?

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
rawRDD.map(_.split(' ').view(4, 6).map(_.toFloat).reduce(_*_).toString)
```

Comment: it gave me an error:

value * is not a member of (Float, Float)